# How can I change the project in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

When configuring the Big-Query command line tool I was asked to set up a default project. However, now I have many projects and I can't happen to find how do I switch from one project to the other. Does someone know how to navigate the projects using the command line? Thanks in advance!

G

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have two ways to do it:

- Specify `--project_id` global flag in `bq`. Example: `bq ls -j --project_id <PROJECT>`
- Change default project by issuing `gcloud config set project <PROJECT>`

Comment: This solution also helps when `bq` sets `project_id` in `.bigqueryrc`, but this parameter is ignored in favor of the one set by `gcloud config`. In this case, `bq` returns "BigQuery error in ls operation: Not found".

Comment: On a clean install, `bq` does _not_ seem to read from `gcloud config`, instead asking the user to select a default project. Is there a way to set the default project (or get `bq` to read from `gcloud`'s)?

Answer (score 2):

We were also facing the same issue, and tried the setting `--project_id` param and default project using `gcloud config set project` command, but no luck.

Then we created the `.bigqueryrc` file and passed the path via `--bigqueryrc` flag, it worked.

content of the **.bigqueryrc** file

```
--project_id=gcp_project_id
```

**Example:**

```
bq --bigqueryrc=/path_to_file/.bigqueryrc ls -j
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#setting_default_values_for_command-line_flags

Comment: bq 2.0.74 no longer seems to respect `--project_id` in the bigqueryrc.

Answer (score 2):

The default project that `bq` respected for me was stored in `$HOME/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default` (Linux)

Answer (score 0):

In my case all aforementioned options were overridden by a key `"quota_project_id"` in `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`

```
"quota_project_id": "my-project",
```